# Why does unanswered:newest show an answered question?

Tags: bug, ios-app

Look at the first question appearing in this photo:

[image: Bug]

Why does it show the question if it's answered?

Comment: Does the answer have an upvote? The SE definition of unanswered is "a question with *no upvoted* answers"

Comment: And if the a question does have an upvoted answer, then it could also be caching.

Comment: @ChrisF Oooh, yeah I was trying to find the def but where do I look?  Anyway, post that as an answer please so I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack Exchange definition of an unanswered question is one with *no upvoted* answers.

So if the answer is at score 0 (or less) the question will appear on the unanswered list. Even if it is at +1 if still might appear on the list due to caching.

On the main sites you can get a list of completely unanswered questions using the link:

```
<site>/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers
```